# how to nest LaTeX documents

Tags: nesting

I'd like to nest load one document inside another, skipping the preamble and `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` of the nested document.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
% load some packages here
\begin{document}
\loaddocument{otherdocument}
text
\end{document}
```

should be the same as if `\loaddocument` were replaced with `\input` except that only the bits between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` of otherdocument.tex are loaded.

I could probably achieve this using `LuaLaTeX` but I can't be the first to be looking for this functionality yet I can't find a solution on this forum.  Is there an existing solution?

****** EDIT ******

I thank Sam Carter for pointing out `subfiles` but that package doesn't allow packages to be loaded in the preamble.  If the nested file is like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x=\quad y.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

then compilation stops, so the `subfiles` package won't do.

The closest to what I have in mind, judging by its documentation, is `newclude` but that package is old and the documentation claims it provides an `\includeenv` command, which LaTeX doesn't recognize.  But, unless something changes, I'll accept that answer and write my own LuaLaTeX routine.

*** SECOND EDIT ***

fwiw, I have written a simple LuaLaTeX routine that takes care of the problem.

Comment: I guess you're looking for the `standalone` package.

Comment: Great, thanks @egreg!  Any gotchas, other than turning page size correction off?

Comment: there are several  packages that do this but normally it's simpler and more robust to put the body of the `otherdocument` in a separate file that can be input into both its own preamble in `otherdocument.tex` and in to the current document.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I'm aware of that possibility.  When you say `more robust`, what issues are you referring to?

Comment: any package doing anything else has to make some local definitions to make the preamble be ignored, there are several approaches one could take for that (the simplest being just `\def\documentclass#1\begin{\begin}` plus a local definition of the document enviornment to do nothing, but any such local definition has the possibility of breaking something, that's just how tex is:-)

Comment: @JPi maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375349/36296

Comment: Thanks @samcarter: unfortunately, that package isn't helpful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was thinking of just writing a LuaLaTeX routine that skips everything up to and including `\begin{document}` and everything from `\end{document}` to the end.....  Should be pretty robust.

Comment: @JPi Out of curiosity, what is the problem with the answer I linked to?

Comment: @samcarter it complains about the `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the nested document (see the code fragment at the bottom of my question).  It appears that one can't load packages in the nested document.

Comment: @JPi Thanks for your reply, I did not notice your edit before!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Five Options:

1. The [`standalone`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en) package.
2. The [`subfiles`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package.
3. The [`docmute`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/docmute) package.
4. The [`combine`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/combine) package.
5. The [`newclude`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newclude) package.

The `standalone` package is designed to *allow* portions of a larger document to be extracted and compiled alone, yet maintaining its place in the larger document. As such the sub-documents need to use the `standalone` *document class*.

The `subfiles` package is a different implementation of the same main idea: the child documents are parasite `subfiles` document class that should know about the main document to take the preamble when compiled alone (whereas the  `standalone` could use  a Borg assimilation strategy).

The `docmute` is yet another implementation of the same main idea, but   child documents can use any document class (there are no `docmute` class) that are truly independent files. Simply, the preambles of child documents are discarded when combined, so your responsibility take care that the main preamble  have all packages needed for all the subdocuments. Use a common `\input{preamble}` avoid troubles in this sense.

The result could be the same for simple documents with the threee pacages, but whilst the first have many useful options, in certain situations some  alternatives could be better (Fran note: Do not pay me much attention, but I vaguely remember some problem working with both `import` and `standalone` that was solved switching to `docmute`).

The `combine` package is designed for bundling of papers into a larger publication (such as for the preparation of conference proceedings). All individual documents should be of the same document class (but unlike `standalone` they can all be `article`, or `report` etc.) There is no need to change the original individual documents at all (unlike the case of using `standalone` to assemble multiple existing files). However, by design the bibliographies, table of contents, section numbering, etc. are *local* to each individual paper. There are also a `journal` document class have the same purpose, but it is specific for the `paper`  (article-like) document class.

The `newclude` package defines an experimental command `\includeenv` which includes exactly the content within a single environment in the sub-documents. If multiple instances of the environment were used, you can optionally specify which instance to include. By specifying as the name of your environment `document`, it should do what you want as described in your question. (But if you loaded any packages in your sub-document, it is your responsibility to load it also in the master.)

As you can see from reading their documentations, most packages are designed for different use-cases. It is up to you to decide which fits your need best.

Comment: (I do not claim that these are the only three options, but only the three I know about, packaged on CTAN.)

Comment: Thanks Willie.... I'll accept it, but I'll be doing something else.

Comment: Add `docmute` to the list.

Comment: @Fran: I am not familiar with docmute, if you don't mind, can you edit the answer to include it with a short paragraph about its pros and cons? Thanks!

Comment: @WillieWong Done. I added some more. Please modify as you like.